# How can I get a tuple from a list by one of the values?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a phoenix `req_headers` list with tuples like `{key, value}`. How can I get value of a tuple by its key from the list? Like that:

```
[{"host", "localhost:4000"}, {"user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"}, {"accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*"}, {"accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.5"}, {"accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate"}, {"content-type", "application/json;charset=utf-8"}, {"referer", "http://localhost:4000/"}, {"content-length", "16"}, {"connection", "keep-alive"}]
```

And I want to fetch a value for key "host" which is "http://localhost:4000". How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general solution is `List.keyfind/3`. When it comes to headers in Plug, there's a special function - [`Plug.Conn.get_req_header/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#get_req_header/2):

```
get_req_header(conn, "host")
#=> ["localhost:4000"]
```